# How the set of solutions of system of linear equations over finite field GF(2) is expressed?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I already know how the set of solutions of system of linear equations over real numbers infinite field $\Bbb{R}$ is expressed.

When there is only single solution then it is just a vector of scalars, where each scalar is a real number.

When there are more than 1 solution, and actually infinite solutions, then it is just a parametric linear vector space in the form: $\forall t \in \Bbb{R}: \vec p+\vec v \cdot t$ where $\vec p \in \Bbb{R}^n \land \vec v \in \Bbb{R}^n$ where $n$ denotes the number of real variables in each linear equation thus $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

But my question is how the set of solutions of system of linear equations over the finite field $\Bbb{Z}_2$ or galois field GF(2) is expressed?

I already know that when there is only single solution then it is also just a vector of scalars, **but** where each scalar is a binary number either zero or one in $\Bbb{Z}_2$ where $\Bbb{Z}_2=$ {0,1}, but when there are more than 1 solution, but always finite number of solutions, then how are they expressed?

Is this similar to how real solutions are expressed by parametric linear vector space by modulo 2? Or something else? I don't know. I am trying to google the answer for this question for days but I don't find the answer anywhere. It seems like nobody talks about this topic.

Do you know how?

Comment: It's the same over any field $K$. The set of solutions (possibly empty) is a coset of a $K$-subspace $V\subset K^n$ ($n$ is the number of variables). Here $V$ is the space of solutions of the homogeneous variant of the system. So to parametrize them you find a basis of $V$ and then add any linear combination of the basis vectors to a particular solution.

Comment: I didn't much understand your comment. Can you please explain me with more details, examples, mathjax code rendering and images? If your comment is an answer to my question, then you should post it as an answer to my question not as a comment to my question.

Comment: Your description of the solution space in real linear algebra is incorrect: it only covers the cases where the solution space is one dimensional or less. As a simple counter-example, consider the solution space to $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @Erez: The point here is that "it works over GF(2) the same way as it does over the reals" is generally enough explanation -- any general answer is basically going to be something between that and completely replicating introductory linear algebra. If you are having trouble seeing how to do linear algebra over GF(2) in exactly the same way you do it over the reals, better answers could be given if you elaborate more precisely on exactly what you're having trouble translating over from the reals to GF(2).

Comment: (and I suspect the *actual* problem here is, as per my first comment, is that you have a misconception about how it works with higher dimensional solution spaces -- but the first time your misconception caused problems was over GF(2), and you're misassigning the blame for your confusion to GF(2), rather than to higher dimension)

Comment: If this suppose to answer my question then you should post this as an answer to my question not as a comment. How can I award you 100 of my reputations if you post as a comment and not as an answer? Note that the bounty is ending tomorrow! Be quick! And thank you for answering my question by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theory of linear equations works exactly the same way no matter the field. Let $k$ a field and $A\in M_n(k)$.

The most relevant result is Kronecker-Capelli theorem:

> Linear system $Ax = b$ has solution if and only if
>   $\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{rank}[A|b]$ where $[A|b]$
>   denotes augmented system matrix.

In that case, let $x_0$ be a particular solution of the system, i.e. $Ax_0 = b$. Then the solution set $S$ of homogeneous linear system $Ax = 0$ is vector space of dimension $n-\operatorname{rank} A$ and all solutions of the system $Ax = b$ are given by $$\{x_0+x\mid Ax = 0\} = x_0+S.$$

These results are elementary and will be found in any Linear Algebra textbook. However, it is important to note that ground field $k$ is completely irrelevant in this context, be it $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ or whatever. It becomes relevant in spectral theory, though.

Comment: Just because that the second person did**n't** get the reward and his/her answer was **not** marked that was the reason that he/she had necessarily to delete his/her answer!? For me his/her answer was both fine and okay.

Comment: Answerers are free to choose to delete any (unaccepted) answer as they want.  Not one forced him/her to do so; though I would suggest that it seems you were looking for a complete solution, and so an answer that answers your "explicit" question is shunned by way of accepting an answer that spoon-feeds you: step-by-step, assuming you are incapable of figuring this out on your own.  The other answer was given, with the confidence that you could continue from there.  I don't know about you, but I much prefer interacting with folks who recognize my capabilities.

Comment: @amWhy, you are making presumptions I don't agree with, concretely: "assuming you are incapable of figuring this out on your own". Reconstructing theorems on your own is amazing thing, but that's not really how math education works most of the times. You are entitled to your opinion, though.